# Why do the periods of a meromorphic fuction form a discrete module?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, periodic-functions

I've come across this statement:

> If $f$ is a nonconstant meromorphic function, the module $M$ containing
>   all its periods cannot have an accumulation point, since otherwise $f$ would
>   be a constant. Therefore each point in $M$ is isolated. In other words, $M$ is
>   a discrete module.

Now it is my understanding that

- an accumulation point $x$ of $M$ is a point for which every open neighbourhood   contains infinitely many points of $M$.
- an isolated point $x$ of $M$ is a point for wich there is a neighbourhood containing only $x$.

I can't see how the absence of an accumulation point implies that every point in $M$ is isolated. I understand that it implies that a neighbourhood of $x$ cannot contain  infinitely many points of $M$, but what prevents such a neighbourhood from containing finitely many?

Comment: Your explanation of isolated points is wrong. What you wrote is the definition of a _limit point_ of $M$. Since we're working in a Hausdorff space, limit points and accumulation points are the same. An _isolated point_ of $M$ is an $x\in M$ such that there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ with $U \cap M = \{x\}$.

Comment: Finite sets are closed (since $\mathbb{C}$ is Hausdorff, hence $T_1$), so if $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, and $F$ a finite set with $x\notin F$, then $U\setminus F$ is also a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Also, if $M\cap U$ is finite (and not equal to $\{x\}$), then $$\delta := \min \bigl\{ \lvert x-y\rvert : y \in (M\cap U)\setminus \{x\}\bigr\}$$ is strictly positive, as the minimum of finitely many strictly positive numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a neighbourhood $U$ of $x\in M$ such that $U\cap M$ is finite, consider $F := (M\cap U)\setminus \{x\}$. If $F = \varnothing$, we're done, otherwise note that $F$ is closed, since it's finite (and $\mathbb{C}$ is Hausdorff, hence $T_1$), and thus $V := U \setminus F$ is also a neighbourhood of $x$, and by construction we have $V\cap M = \{x\}$.

An argument using the metric is that then

$$\delta = \min \{ \lvert x-y\rvert : y\in F\} > 0,$$

since it is the minimum of finitely many (strictly) positive numbers. Then choose $r$ so small that $B_r(x) \subset U$ and set $\rho = \min \{r,\delta\}$. Then $B_\rho(x) \cap M = \{x\}$.